# Java - Quarkus, should helper/utility classes be considered beans?

Tags: java, quarkus

Hi y'all I was creating a utiltiy class something like this to assist with logging. Now I can't use the @Inject annotation in quarkus unless I make this utility class a bean.

But my question is that should utility classes who's only purpose is something like printing to log be a bean? or should I make it a final class with static methods?

Comment: Utility classes are bad design. Printing to log shouldn't be a bean.

Comment: @Kayaman the part with the "printing to log" is debatable. If we, for example, want some convenient methods that set values in the MDC context, log a message and then unset said values again... then a small service might actually be useful.

Comment: @Turing85 that doesn't sound like a very common use of MDC compared to for example having a filter handle the init/clear. But in any case this sounds like something that has a lot better solution than some kind of utility bean.

Comment: @Kayaman it becomes "more common" when we use an ELK-/ELF stack for log aggregation and configure the application to send the whole MDC context to ElasticSearch.